# Refreshing MVC DropDownListFor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm using jQuery to re-populate a `DropDownListFor` using the following code:

```
$('#Teste).change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Teste/Teste/Teste/' + $(this).val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var ddl = $('#TesteTw);
                    ddl.empty();
                    $(data).each(function () {
                        ddl.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: this.Value
                        }).html(this.Text));
                    });
                }
            });        
});
```

But the HTML doesn't refresh, I still got the same items on the `DropDownList`.

Although if I get the `DropDownList` values with jQuery I get the updated values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing quote on the following lines:

```
$('#Teste).change(function () { // should be $('#Teste').change(function () {
var ddl = $('#TesteTw);         // should be var ddl = $('#TesteTw');
```

Also, the way you're iterating over the returned data, which I'm assuming is an array is not idea.  Consider doing the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ddl.append(
        $('<option/>')
            .val(data[i])
            .html(data[i].Text)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, I've modified the each method:

```
$('#Teste').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Teste/Teste/Teste/' + $(this).val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var ddl = $('#TesteTw');
                    ddl.empty();
                    $(data).each(function () {
                       ddl.append(
                           $("<option />", {
                               value: this.Value,
                               text: this.Text});
                       //OR
                       ddl.append(
                           $("<option />")
                               .attr("value", this.Value)
                               .text(this.Text));
                    });
                }
            });        
});
```